NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater
import logging

from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType


def create_keyspace(session):
    session.execute("""
        CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS spark_streams
        WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'};
    """)

    print("Keyspace created successfully!")


def create_table(session):
    session.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS spark_streams.created_users (
        id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
        first_name TEXT,
        last_name TEXT,
        gender TEXT,
        address TEXT,
        post_code TEXT,
        email TEXT,
        username TEXT,
        registered_date TEXT,
        phone TEXT,
        picture TEXT);
    """)

    print("Table created successfully!")


def insert_data(session, **kwargs):
    print("inserting data...")

    user_id = kwargs.get('id')
    first_name = kwargs.get('first_name')
    last_name = kwargs.get('last_name')
    gender = kwargs.get('gender')
    address = kwargs.get('address')
    postcode = kwargs.get('post_code')
    email = kwargs.get('email')
    username = kwargs.get('username')
    dob = kwargs.get('dob')
    registered_date = kwargs.get('registered_date')
    phone = kwargs.get('phone')
    picture = kwargs.get('picture')

    try:
        session.execute("""
            INSERT INTO spark_streams.created_users(id, first_name, last_name, gender, address, 
                post_code, email, username, dob, registered_date, phone, picture)
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
        """, (user_id, first_name, last_name, gender, address,
              postcode, email, username, dob, registered_date, phone, picture))
        logging.info(f"Data inserted for {first_name} {last_name}")

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'could not insert data due to {e}')


def create_spark_connection():
    s_conn = None

    try:
        s_conn = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName('SparkDataStreaming') \
            .config('spark.jars.packages', "com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12:3.5.1,"
                                           "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.1") \
            .config('spark.cassandra.connection.host', 'localhost') \
            .getOrCreate()

        s_conn.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
        logging.info("Spark connection created successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Couldn't create the spark session due to exception {e}")

    return s_conn


def connect_to_kafka(spark_conn):
    spark_df = None
    try:
        spark_df = spark_conn.readStream \
            .format('kafka') \
            .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', 'broker:29092') \
            .option('subscribe', 'users_created') \
            .option('startingOffsets', 'earliest') \
            .load()
        logging.info("kafka dataframe created successfully")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning(f"kafka dataframe could not be created because: {e}")

    return spark_df


def create_cassandra_connection():
    try:
        # connecting to the cassandra cluster
        cluster = Cluster(['localhost'])

        cas_session = cluster.connect()

        return cas_session
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Could not create cassandra connection due to {e}")
        return None


def create_selection_df_from_kafka(spark_df):
    schema = StructType([
        StructField("id", StringType(), False),
        StructField("first_name", StringType(), False),
        StructField("last_name", StringType(), False),
        StructField("gender", StringType(), False),
        StructField("address", StringType(), False),
        StructField("post_code", StringType(), False),
        StructField("email", StringType(), False),
        StructField("username", StringType(), False),
        StructField("registered_date", StringType(), False),
        StructField("phone", StringType(), False),
        StructField("picture", StringType(), False)
    ])

    sel = spark_df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)") \
        .select(from_json(col('value'), schema).alias('data')).select("data.*")
    print(sel)

    return sel


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create spark connection
    spark_conn = create_spark_connection()

    if spark_conn is not None:
        # connect to kafka with spark connection
        spark_df = connect_to_kafka(spark_conn)
        selection_df = create_selection_df_from_kafka(spark_df)
        session = create_cassandra_connection()

        if session is not None:
            create_keyspace(session)
            create_table(session)

            logging.info("Streaming is being started...")

            streaming_query = (selection_df.writeStream.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                               .option('checkpointLocation', '/tmp/checkpoint')
                               .option('keyspace', 'spark_streams')
                               .option('table', 'created_users')
                               .start())

            streaming_query.awaitTermination()

24/04/16 17:04:52 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = fd356234-6b1c-48c1-a7dd-50c1ba59b5d0, runId = c7db0d89-ed5c-4a08-84c6-11de795fb939] terminated with error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.StreamingQueryException: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = fd356234-6b1c-48c1-a7dd-50c1ba59b5d0, runId = e065e0bb-d1e5-4886-b84d-974839546e85] terminated with exception: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater
i've used a docker setup where data froma  api is pushed to kafka broker
and from there spark is trying to stream it to cassandra
all the services in docker are up but i'm gettig a
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.StreamingQueryException: [STREAM_FAILED]
exception: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater
python -3.10
pyspark-3.5.1
spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.5.1.jar
spark-cassandra-connector-assembly_2.12-3.5.0.jar
kafka-clients-3.7.0.jar
therse are the jars added
How to resolve this any possible solutions
